# Spring MVC and AngularJS routing conflict

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, routes

**Hi Guys.**
I have problem with routing between Spring MVC and AngularJS.

So, when I got homepage : http://localhost:8080/ captures that Angular and its ok but when i want go to another page e.g http://localhost:8080/dashboard captures that Spring MVC and Tomcat show error 404 Not Found.
To get to dashboard in need use url **/#/dashbaord**

Although i got below code in my file with routing configuration.

It is possible to angular was first taken into consideration and next Spring MVC?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
                        enabled : true,
                        requireBase : false
                    });
```

**Regards**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to route all Tomcat URLs to index.html

For API calls to Spring Boot http://localhost:8080/springbootapi/wotever

And in Tomcat say DO NOT POINT ANY URL WITH /springbootapi/ in it to index.html

EVERYTHING ELSE TO index.html

Pointing everything else to index.html gives Angular full control over everything except API calls

The above outline the generic approach to do this.

Maybe better to follow this tutorial ...

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/